# FormData is ignored in specific page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I meet ridiculous problem while try to send FormData with XHR in IE10.
I found that FormData is ignored in specific page with same code as below.

What can be guessed as reason?
The pages has same DOCTYPE.

```
var o = new FormData(); 
o.append("test", "1234"); 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("POST", "/files"); 
xhr.send(o);
```

In normal case:

```
POST https://github.com/files HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7de290c360a6e
Referer: (something)
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ja;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1;; APCPMS=^N20120502090046254556C65BBCE3E22DEE3F_477^; Trident/6.0; TCO_20140226091802)
Host: github.com
Content-Length: 143
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: (deleted)

-----------------------------7de290c360a6e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

1234
-----------------------------7de290c360a6e--
```

In abnormal case:

```
POST http://foo.bar.com/files HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7de1b67c0afe
Referer: http://foo.bar.com/page
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ja;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1;;     APCPMS=^N20120502090046254556C65BBCE3E22DEE3F_477^; Trident/6.0; TCO_20140226091802)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Host: dhive.nhnre.com:8888
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: (deleted)
```

Comment: [Same-Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)?

Comment: @Boaz I think it cannot be, cuz sending request to relative path.